# How can I confirm the "change screen resolution dialog" in Windows 10 using keyboard only?

Tags: windows-10, display, resolution

As in previous versions of Windows, a user can change the screen resolution or the monitor setup in Windows 10 using the control panel. However, the dialog that asks for confirmation ("Do you really want to change the screen resolution?") has a button with a timeout of approximately 15 seconds. If you do not press this button within the desired period of time, the changes will be reverted, probably in order to prevent the user from switching any resolution that their monitor setup does not support.

Unfortunately, this button is only accessible by mouse, or at least I fail to find a Shortcut (like Alt-y for "yes"), so the very simple question is:

How can this button be accessed using only a keyboard?

I have attached a screenshot to indicate what the dialog looks like, it's in German language because this is the only test system available at the moment.

[image: Screen resolution change confirmation dialog]

Answer (score 28):

Press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, then <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Space</kbd>.

Comment: I think the arrow keys may also work in this context, but I'm not exactly sure. On a message box (like a "Yes No Cancel" one, when you edit a file), if a button is pre-selected, it works. I'm not sure if those count or not.

Comment: If memory serves this dialog always defaults to the right-hand button so you need a TAB to select the other button and then SPACE or ENTER to "press" it.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel The arrow keys don't work here.  Also, If you have changed your mouse settings, "Pointer Options" -> "Snap To" on,  you would still need to do the TAB first.

Comment: @MarkStewart I noticed it doesn't have a button pre-selected. Makes sense that it doesn't work.